# Distinct sums for edge weights

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, algorithms, trees

For each $n\geq1$, consider a special tree with $2n+1$ nodes which are assigned values $a_i$ from the set $\{0,0,1,2,3,\dots,2n-1\}$. Only $0$ can be a repeated assignment.

The edges are only the ones connecting $a_{2i}$ to $a_{2i+2}$ and $a_{2i+1}$ to $a_{2i+2}$. Then, the edge connecting $x$ and $y$ has weight $x+y$.

Here are [some figures](http://dauns01.math.tulane.edu/%7Etamdeberhan/some_drawings.pdf) for an illustrative purpose for the special trees we focus on.

**GOAL:** Make the edge-weights $a_i+a_j$ mutually distinct modulo $2n$.

Example: if $2n+1=3$ then $a_0=a_2=0, a_1=1$ works, mod $2$.

Example: if $2n+1=5$ then $a_0=a_3=0, a_1=1, a_2=3, a_4=2$, mod $4$.

> **QUESTION.** Is it always possible to real the above goal?

Comment: ?? If there's an edge connecting $a_i$ and $a_j$ for each $i$ and $j$, then that's not a tree. Can you tell us here what the trees are, instead of making us go offsite to find out?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I've added a few lines to clarify this.

Comment: So, the $a_i$ are both the values of the nodes, and the names of the nodes? And the node named $a_{2n-1}$ is isolated?

Comment: Yes, both the value and the name. I was hoping the pictures in the link shade more light into it, if you can view them.

Comment: So there are two nodes with the name $a_0$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.